# Resolving a circular dependency in C# using MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, circular-dependency

#### TL:DR;

Is there a way to resolve a "partial" circular dependency between C# projects using MSBuild wizardry? ‍♂️

#### Long version

We have a project A that depends on project B. `A.csproj` looks like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\projectB\B.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now project B needs a type from Project A. VS prevents us from adding a reference to project A (circular dependency) but it doesn't complain when we add a link to the specific file, like so in `B.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\projectA\ClassA.cs" Link="ClassA.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The problem appears when we use `ClassA` on project A. Now VS complains (rightfully) about multiple declarations of ClassA ([CS0436](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0436) - we have set warnings as errors), one from each project.

I am aware that this shows that our design is flawed and as other answers here in SO indicate the right solution would be to refactor. If this is not possible due to time constraints, is there any MSBuild trick that would allow projectA to compile?

#### For reference, things that I tried and don’t work

- In `A.csproj`: set `ReferenceOutputAssembly=false` from project B.
  => Would work if project A doesn’t need anything from B.
- In `B.csproj`: include and then remove

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="..\circdependency\ClassA.cs" Link="ClassA.cs" />
   <Compile Remove="ClassA.cs" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

- In `B.csproj`: `CopyToOutputDirectory=Never`

Other options that work but are not ideal:

- Suppressing the warning.
- Duplicating `ClassA` in project B and using a different namespace, making it internal etc.

Comment: You'll need to move the common types into a separate library, which is used by them both. If you are aware of a "flawed design" _(not my words)_ you shouldn't give in. It really bites you in the butt once or more.

Comment: Then you'll need to shift the type, or at least it's interface, into project B. Just because project A has the implementation, doesn't prevent project B from defining the contract.